# how to config Groups-base policies about keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am keycloak freshman.
I want to create a fairly simple groups-based access control system using Keycloak's authorizaion system.
I try to config a groups-based policy but failure,my step as following:

1.Creating a group name of "user",
2.Configing resource,scope and so on 
3.Setting policies as Group-base policy,but in this step ,this is something confused about me "Groups Claim",the description of "Groups Claim" is :
"A claim to use as the source for users group. If the claim is present it must be an array of strings". 
follow this description i configed the "[user]" in this field.

Is there something wrong with me configuration?
Could someone can give me some guidance?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Usually with keycloak you are doing authorization by using **roles**. Groups then can be utilized to associate roles to multiple users (the users of the groups).
If you need more fine-grained authorization capabilities than *roles*, you can have a look at keycloak's authorization sub-system with resources, permissions, policies and authorization scopes.
But for simplicity I recommend starting with roles.